# Sound output on my PC isn't obeying my volume controls

Tags: windows-10, audio

I've gotten my PC to output sound to the device I want. The volume mixer shows that sound is coming through the headphones. When I mute it, the green bar in the volume mixer disappears, but it doesn't actually mute the sound. Raising or lowering the sound does nothing to the outputted sound either.

My headphones are set to the default playback device, and I have been able to control the volume on them using the volume mixer before.

Comment: Sounds like driver problem. Download the latest drivers from motherboard manufacturer website or sound card manufacturer website.

Comment: I've updated my audio drivers and restarted. Didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on to where do the headphones are connected to ? What type of sound card ?

Comment: My headphones are connected to an astro mixamp which is connected to my asus Z170 motherboard that handles the audio.

Comment: From what i see on astro website, the mixamp is connected to the pc via optical cable, is that correct?

Comment: That is an option, but I had the same difficulties using that cable so I switched to using the 3.5 mm jacks for the headphones and microphone.

Comment: So once again, into what port on the back of your motherboard did you connect the cable ? Or you have a dedicated sound card ?

Comment: If you don't mind, I would happily take a look via remote control session like team viewer.

Comment: I have one 3.5mm cable plugged into the mixamp which splits into two 3.5 mm ends, one for the microphone and one for the headphones. The green headphone end is plugged into the green port and the pink microphone end is plugged into the pink port.

Comment: Bypassing the mixamp and plugging the headphones directly into the pc causes them to react to pc volume changes

Comment: So why don't the same thing happens when they're plugged through the mixamp ?! :/ may be you are trying to control the wrong output ?!

Comment: On the windows mixer what do you select as the default playback device ?

Comment: I had it setup to play through headset earphone (2-ASTRO MixAmp Pro), which was the device windows was showing outputting audio. Now my pc thinks it's playing things through speakers, but it's actually coming out of the headphones through the mixamp and listening to the volume controls. So problem solved? Not sure how I did it, though.

Comment: Problem solved by selecting the correct output a.k.a speakers :))) cause thats the green jack :)))

Comment: The microphone is still set to Headset Microphone, not just Microphone, and seems to be working.